# Efficiently partition Pandas DataFrame rows such that the sum of a column is at least X in each partition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose we have the following DataFrame with a single `weight` column.

```py
>>> pd.DataFrame(dict(weight=[1, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9, 5, 6, 5, 5, 4, 9]))
    weight
0        1
1        3
2        5
3        6
4        8
5        9
6        5
7        6
8        5
9        5
10       4
11       9
```

The goal is to assign a partition number to each row such that:

1. Every partition has a sum of `weights` of at least some threshold.
2. Only contiguous rows can belong in the same partition.
3. Each partition contains has as few rows as possible.

If we use a threshold of 10, the expected output for the above DataFrame would be:

```py
>>> pd.DataFrame(dict(
    weight=[1, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9, 5, 6, 5, 5, 4, 9],
    partition=[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4]
))
    weight  partition
0        1          0
1        3          0
2        5          0
3        6          0
4        8          1
5        9          1
6        5          2
7        6          2
8        5          3
9        5          3
10       4          4
11       9          4
```

It is easy to implement this transformation by iterating over the rows and keeping a running total of the "weight" column which resets after the threshold is hit or exceeded.

```py
def slow_partition(df: pd.DataFrame, min_partition_total_weight: int) -> pd.DataFrame:
    partition_ids = []
    current_parition = 0
    current_partition_total_weight = 0
    for weight in df["weight"]:
        if current_partition_total_weight >= min_partition_total_weight:
            current_parition += 1
            current_partition_total_weight = 0
        partition_ids.append(current_parition)
        current_partition_total_weight += weight
    return df.assign(partition=partition_ids)
```

Although this implementation has the correct behavior, it is pure python and therefore does not scale well to larger DataFrames. Are there any `pandas` functions or `DataFrame` methods that can help perform this transformation in a vectorized manner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recursive calculations are not vectorisable, for improve performance is used  [**numba**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/enhancingperf.html#numba-jit-compilation):

```
import numba

@numba.jit(nopython=True)
def cumgroup(x, min_partition_total_weight):
    current_partition_total_weight = 0.
    current_parition = 0
    out = np.empty_like(x)
    for i, y in enumerate(x):
        if current_partition_total_weight >= min_partition_total_weight:
            current_partition_total_weight = 0.
            current_parition += 1
        out[i] = current_parition
        current_partition_total_weight += y
    return out

df = df.assign(partition=cumgroup(df["weight"].to_numpy(), 10))
print (df)
    weight  partition
0        1          0
1        3          0
2        5          0
3        6          0
4        8          1
5        9          1
6        5          2
7        6          2
8        5          3
9        5          3
10       4          4
11       9          4
```

Comment: Thank you! It should have been obvious it isn't possible to vectorize an operation where each element's value depends on the value of other elements, but I apparently needed a reminder. Numba works perfectly for my use case.